# A question about method overriding in c#

Tags: c#

```
class xxx
{
   public virtual void function1()
   {
     // Some code here
   }
}

class  yyy : xxx
{
   public override void function1()
   {
    // some code here
   }
}

class result
{
   public result(){}

   // In the main i write as

   xxx xobj = new yyy();
   xobj.function1(); // by calling this function1 in yyy will invoked

   yyy yobj = new xxx();
   yobj.function1()     // which function will be called here
}
```

ple

Comment: This won't compile - you can't assign an instance of `xxx` to `yyy`

Comment: Maybe you should try running your own code! It won't compile. You can't explicitly convert `xxx` to `yyy`.

Comment: Before asking questions like this one and your last one, please fire up a compiler and verify that your sample code at least compiles. It makes it very difficult to focus on the issue at hand when the sample code doesn't make any sense. Better yet, while you're verifying the sample code, see what the output is and *then* ask questions about **why** that's the output if it's not what you expect.

Answer (score 5):

Well, first of all:

```
yyy yobj = new xxx();
yobj.function1();
```

will cause a compile error.  `yyy` is a `xxx`, but `xxx` is not a `yyy`.

Secondly:

```
xxx xobj = new yyy();
xobj.function1();
```

will cause `function1()` of class `xxx` to be executed because the variable is of type `xxx`.  to call the method on class `yyy` you will need to cast the variable to type `yyy`

```
xxx xobj = new yyy();
((yyy)xobj).function1();
```

Comment: Great sample of not pedantic but thinking SO user, +1

Answer (score 3):

This is a classic common misconception about inheritance. Inheritance is not bidirectional. By this I mean that a sub class is a type of a super class .. but it is not true the other way around.

```
public class Base
{
}

public class Sub : Base
{
}


Base baseObj = new Base(); //this is just fine
Base subAsBase = new Sub(); //this is just fine, a Sub is a type of Base

Sub subAsBase = new Base(); //this will spit a compile error. A Base is NOT a type of Sub, it is the other way around.
```

Likewise, I could perform the following casting:

```
Base baseObj = null;
Sub subObj = new Sub();
baseObj = subObj; //now I am storing a sub instance object in a variable declared as Base

Sub castedSubObj = baseObj as Sub; //simply casted it back to it's concrete type
```

Comment: The question is not about inheritance, it is about overridden methods.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot cast xxx to yyy, so `yyy yobj = new xxx();` won't compile

Comment: Even though the question is not 100% correct - it is not an answer.

Comment: @zerkms: What *is* the answer? It's extremely challenging to answer questions like this that don't make any sense. This answer is just as valid as any other. There's no way to know what the problem being asked about is if the code doesn't even compile in the first place.

Comment: @Cody I agree with you. That was not a valid reason to down vote.

Comment: @Zerkms You are failing to attempt being pedantic! The code will not compile. Therefore, no method would ever be invoked! The answer is correct. +1 to break even.

Comment: @Cody Gray: I'm still sure that the question comments were developed to make such notices. The question itself is about inheritance and overridden methods and I expect that the only possible answer should be also specifically about that stuff. The @Kyle Trauberman's answer is the sample of great answer for even such bad written question.

Comment: @Matthew Cox: even though the code won't compile we all understand what OP meant. Let's not being pedantic and find bugs and typos in OPs code.

Comment: @zerkms: How do you know that's what the question is about? Maybe he tried the code and couldn't figure out why it didn't work, and just *assumed* the problem had to do with method overloading. It's really impossible to say. I agree that I'd probably leave this as a comment, but that's no reason it's any worse an answer than the others. You keep saying tht "we all knew what the OP meant", but I honestly didn't and still don't. I'm not very good at mind-reading.

Comment: @zerkms I Agree with Cody again. It is a common misconception that inheritance works in both directions. This appears to be a clean cut case of this issue.

Comment: @Cody Gray: OP definitely understands what he is talking about. He just made a mistake writing stub sample directly in browser without tests. "but I honestly didn't and still don't" --- well, don't answer then if you can't get the question, or ask additional questions in comments.

Comment: @Matthew Cox: the question is not about why code is not compile, but about overridden methods. He just *made a mistake*

Comment: @zerkms: The inability to write questions that make sense is the fault of the asker, not the answerer. My point is that this is not a bad answer because it fails at reading the mind of the asker. This isn't a mistake writing the stub sample in the browser. What do you think the *real* answer to this question is? A lot of people don't understand that inheritance isn't bi-directional; this answer covers that. What else **is there** to the question? Do you have some kind of additional footnote on your screen that I don't see? All I see is some source code that doesn't compile.

Comment: You keep saying he made a mistake, as if that was something we could simply ignore and answer the *rest* of the question. I'm sorry, I don't see the "rest" of the question.

Comment: @Cody Gray: then ask him about additional info. Don't try to guess answer to the incomplete question.

Comment: @zerkms: Still waiting for an answer to the existing comments that already cover my confusion.

Comment: @Cody Gray: lol, a lot of people don't understand physics too. Why don't you answer about some physical thing here? Answer covers some stuff that hasn't been asked about. "Do you have some kind of additional footnote on your screen that I don't see" --- yes, I do, and @Kyle Trauberman does.

Comment: @Cody Gray: waiting is the best you can do, indeed. Waiting of clarification is always better than guessing and being pedantic, imho.

Comment: Yeah, why leave an actual answer that explains what's wrong with the code sample as posted? Much less one that explicitly answers the only **question** that I see in the question, this one in a comment: `// which function will be called here`. The answer, of course, is "neither". I'd talk about physics if it was the reason the code wasn't compiling, fortunately it's not because as you say, people aren't likely to understand that. There's a risk people would drive-by downvote that answer, too, as they wouldn't understand how it was related.

Comment: @Cody Gray: well, when OP will correct his code this answer will be absolutely out of context. That is why comment, not an answer is more correct.

Comment: @zerkms You are simply incorrect. Choose to be pugnacious if you must but the fact remains. The OP hasn't changed his question at all and it clearly is an issue of not understanding inheritance rather than one of method overloading. A simple correlation, if I ask you, zerk "why do pigs fly", you would simply reply, "silly matt, pigs don't fly". This is the exact same situation.

Comment: @Matthew Cox: OP did not clarify the question just because he is afk for now (look at his profile). Well, I cannot agree that the analogy is the same. Well I have my personal opinion and I have expressed (and explained) it with downvote.

Comment: Wow! You have an intensive debate here! As for me, I have seen a question about an invalid code. And my answer have been aimed to let kartnik know that code is invalid. For my opinion, "why do pigs fly" is a very accurate analogy.

Comment: @zerkms: maybe you are right that a question comment is better than answer. But don't you think the difference between them is quite thin here and it is not a reason for downwote?

Comment: @Egor4eg: I think the difference between them is significant.